# netbeans cannot open shared library during RUN command

Tags: netbeans, shared-library

I have issue with NetBeans:

everything worked fine but I've just tried to run my CUDA programs on Linux Ubuntu 12.10 in NetBeans and I get error:

```
dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/my_cuda_1: error while loading shared libraries: libcudart.so.5.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

RUN FAILED (exit value 127, total time: 191ms)
```

the projects can build: compile + link without problems, I can also run it from commandline but if I try run it from NetBeans I get this error. I was able to run it few minutes ago, what might happened?

I have added file my_lib to ld.so.conf.d containing such text:

```
    /usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64:/lib
    /usr/lib
    /usr/lib64
```

can it be a link issue libcudart.so.5.0 -> licudart.so? there are two libs in cuda/lib libcudart.so.5.0 (link) and libcudart.so (link) and libcudart.so.5.0.35 (shared lib) why it complains about .so.5.0? mayve link like: sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3 /usr/lib/libglut.so is necessary

it is related to link to shared library I think

> root@comp:# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-current:/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib::/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64:/lib

this :: is this a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:
SOLVED:

add to the Project->Properties->Environment

> Name: LD_LIBRARY_PATH
>   Value:
>   $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/nvidia-current:/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib:/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64:/lib

but I don't know what happened as it worked before