# LD_LIBRARY_PATH specification

Tags: netbeans, shared-library

I have problem: NetBeans can't open libcudart.so.5.0 when I do RUN, though there is no problem from commandline.
is this :: here

> root@comp:# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-current:/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib::/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64:/lib

a problem?

Comment: This is part of your other question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/267066/netbeans-cannot-open-shared-library-during-run-command

Comment: these are different issues: this could be one question as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED:

add to the Project->Properties->Environment

> Name: LD_LIBRARY_PATH
>   Value:
>   $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/nvidia-current:/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib:/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64:/lib

but I don't know what happened as it worked before