# How to correctly set environment variable (which may not exist)

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I want to set an environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which may or may not exist (it does not seem to exist currently, but I'm not sure if it will at some point).
I have successfully managed to set my own vars, and extend the `PATH` variable as well, by placing my `path.sh` into `/etc/profile.d/` and that works fine, however this new variable just does not seem to work. I have tried extending it or seting it new, with and without if / else (see screenshot). No matter what I do, it simply won't be added to the environment variables and I have no idea why (since it worked before). I did reboot, so that should not be the issue

[image: ScriptAndOutput]

For easier reading, here is the `path.sh` content in text form:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/snap/cmake/current/bin"
export unreal_path="/DevShared/UnrealEngine"
export GRPC_DIR="/DevShared/Dev_SRS/grpc/1.20.0"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/DevShared/UnrealEngine"

#LD_LIBRARY_PATH may not exist
#ldPath="$unreal_path"
#if [ $LD_LIBRARY_PATH -z ]
#then
#    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$ldPath"
#else
#    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ldPath"
#fi

#echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Note that if I call the script via `sudo bash /etc/profile.d/path.sh` with the latter part executing rather than commented out, the bash actually does echo the correct path. Also, that `ldPath` variable was just for testing purposes, it is not actually necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2BAC8-etc.2BAC8-environment):

> Note: You can only set this environment variable inside an interactive shell. Since Ubuntu 9.04 Jaunty Jackalope, LD_LIBRARY_PATH cannot be set in $HOME/.profile, /etc/profile, nor /etc/environment files. You must use /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf configuration files. See Launchpad bug #366728 for more information.

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is reset for security reasons.

You need to add a conf file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`

See also:

- [How to set the environmental variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environmental-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux)
- [How to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH permanently?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/950313/how-to-set-ld-library-path-permanently)
- [LD_LIBRARY_PATH specification](https://askubuntu.com/questions/267071/ld-library-path-specification)
- [setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH for CUDA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210884/setting-ld-library-path-for-cuda)